# How to concatenate two columns in linq to sql query's select projection

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

1- I use linq to sql to query a database table. 

2- In my actual table, I store Phone Country Code, Phone Number and Phone Extension in different columns.

3- When I get the data I need Phone to be equal to concatenation of Phone Country Code, Phone Number and Phone Extension.

4- For some records, any of these 3 columns might have null values.

5- If one column is null, then the whole concatenation yields null.

```
from s in test
select new{
          Phone = s.PhoneCountryCode + s.PhoneNumber + s.PhoneExtension
}
```

6- I tried the following, but didn't work. Still yields null.

```
from s in test
select new{
          Phone = s.PhoneCountryCode == null ? "" : s.PhoneCountryCode + s.PhoneNumber       == null ? "" : s.PhoneNumber + s.PhoneExtension == null ? "" : s.PhoneExtension
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator as follows:

```
from s in test
select new
{
    Phone = (s.PhoneCountryCode ?? "") + (s.PhoneNumber ?? "") + (s.PhoneExtension ?? "")
}
```